# R replace strings not like two strings?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I am using the sub function in R to replace any string that does not start with an M OR does not start with T814. I have the code below that successfully keeps any string starting with M, but it isn't keeping the strings that start with T814.

```
attempt2$dx3 <- sub('^[^M].*| ^[^T814].*', "", attempt2$dx3)
```

Is there any way I can adjust the code to only keep the strings I'm interested in?

This is an example of what I have:

```
attempt2 <- data.frame(dx2 = c("M1234", "T8142", "M745", "T8149", "R234"),
                   dx3 = c("M356", "T1142", "M745", "T8146", "G234"))
```

and what I would like to have:

```
attempt2 <- data.frame(dx2 = c("M1234", "T8142", "M745", "T8149", ""),
                   dx3 = c("M356", "", "M745", "T8146", ""))
```

Comment: For "not (multiple character string)" in regex, I believe your options are (a) use a negative lookahead [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025783), or (b) match the multi-character string and then negate.

Comment: You really do not want `attempt2$dx3 <- sub('(?s)^(?!M|T814).*', "", attempt2$dx3, perl=TRUE)`, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're subbing the whole string, you can detect the  matches and then replace everything that doesn't match:

```
attempt2$dx3[!grepl("^(M|T184)", attempt2$dx3)] <- ""
```

I believe the other option is negative look-ahead, and Wiktor's comment is probably spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
attempt2 %>% 
   mutate(dx3 = replace(dx3, !str_detect(dx3, "^(M|T8146)"), ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy library for this:

```
library(inops)
attempt2 %out~% c("^M", "^T814") <- ""
```

Here `%out~%` matches all elements that do not match the regular expressions specified on the right side. You can then assign a replacement value to this expression at the end of the line.